# Git svn rebase fails

Tags: git, git-svn

I use `git svn` to track a SVN repo.  When I try to do a `git svn rebase` I am getting this error:

```
Incomplete data: Delta source ended unexpectedly
```

This is a large repo, with a long history.  Just fetching the original single revision took almost 90mins, so I don't want to reclone.

Are there any ways to track down which file is causing the error, or any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be similar to SO question "[git svn rebase: Incomplete data: Delta source ended unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211025/git-svn-rebase-incomplete-data-delta-source-ended-unexpectedly)", in that it may be linked to the **[autocrlf option](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes)**.

This [thread on git mailing list](http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2008/7/23/2643214) discusses this issue at length last year in 2008. At the time, the user tried:

> To fix this situation I take full file content from SVN as next revision. This is
>   dump and slow but it works.

What version of Git (or msysGit) are you using? It seems to be a known issue, and I am not sure it has been conclusively fixed.
But first, are you doing some CRLF conversions during your svn to git imports?

Comment: Thanks, setting the autocrlf to false and then a fresh checkout solved the problem.