# Incomplete data: Delta source ended unexpectedly while git svn fetch

Tags: git, git-svn

I have cloned my svn repo into git and everyday i am doing git svn fetch (i only do changes in SVN) but i am planning to move to git and i keep the git repo in sync for the day since the svn clone tooke me 2 weeks (yeah it's a big repo).

Anyway the git svn fetch has worked fine every day until 2 days ago where i now get

```
Incomplete data: Delta source ended unexpectedly at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/Git/SVN/Ra.pm line 290
```

at a specific revision. I tried the different suggestions online about git svn reset and going back some revisions and i went about 20 revisions back with no luck. I also tried to run :

```
git config --get core.autocrlf
```

which gave `true`.

I know that the svn repo is working good, i have no issues doing svn up.

Any ideas how i can get back on track to sync again ? I am stuck without ideas what to try.

I might reveal one issue. I don't recall but before running the issue i might have had a disk full on the disk where the repo is when i tried the fetch. Maybe that destroyed something ?

/donnib

Comment: Hi @dbrasco, did you solve the problem? If yes, please provide an answer. I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure there are no additional git/perl processes running (which could create the **index.lock** file and mess up the current fetch). Kill'em all.
2. Delete the **...\my_repository.git\.git\svn\refs\remotes\trunk\index.lock** file
3. **git svn reset -r SomeSVNRevisionNumberBeforeTheProblematicOne**
4. **git svn fetch**

Fetch should continue from the **SomeSVNRevisionNumberBeforeTheProblematicOne**.

The most probable reason why this happened is concurrency between two git instances running simultaneously on the same repository.

Answer (score 0):

Using `--ignore-paths` sometimes helps, so the steps are:

1. `git svn reset -r <svn-version-before-error>`
2. `git svn fetch --ignore-paths=/branches/badbranch`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved similar problem using -r param. My case was as follow:

- I created /branches/dev branch in SVN  at particular revision, eg 1000 and started using it
- all previous revision were made to /trunk
- I started master branch migration with ***git svn clone***, which got all svn /trunk to git master
- then I've added another fetch config for my svn development branch and resumed the svn fetch

```
# .git/config
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = http://some-repo/path
    fetch = /trunk:refs/remotes/trunk
    fetch = branches/dev:refs/remotes/dev
```

- ***git svn fetch*** complained at revision 999, which belong to /trunk and has been already migrated to git master (*Incomplete data: Delta source ended unexpectedly at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/Git/SVN/Ra.pm* ***line 312***)
- notice error refers to line 312, which might be related to different problem than line 290 referred in this ticket?
- then I run ***git svn fetch -r 1000:HEAD***, which allowed me to migrate all revisions of /branches/dev excluding revisions before creating /branches/dev